# Why is my query finding field entries that are numbers, but not number/letter combinations

Tags: php, mysql

Newbie here.  The following function works fine when $color refers to an entry in the "style" field that is numberic e.g. "5000".  But if the entry is "5000B" or letters entirely, it can't find it. Is this an indexing problem?

```
    function get_shirt_colors_by_style($color)
    {
db_connect();

    $query = "SELECT style,sanmar_mainframe_color,unique_key,color_square_image 
              FROM sanmar_products WHERE style=$color 
              GROUP BY style ORDER BY style";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is failing to find alphanumeric comnbinations because the string is not quoted:

```
$query = "SELECT style,sanmar_mainframe_color,unique_key,color_square_image FROM sanmar_products WHERE style='$color' GROUP BY style ORDER BY style";
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

Numeric values need not be quoted in a MySQL query, but string values must always be surrounded in single quotes like `'5000B'`.

We assume the value of `$color` has already been escaped against SQL injection:

```
// Hopefully this happened already.
// If not, do it before running mysql_query()
$color = mysql_real_escape_string($color);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now I'm going to go shoot myself in the head.

Comment: @dull_bulb Don't. you have so much to live for.

Comment: Certainly worth keeping an eye on with newer versions of MySQL since they'll no longer quietly juggle strings to numbers - MySQL 4 used to let you get away with updating an `INT(10)` with `'37'` for instance... so with MySQL 5 it's "Numeric values _must_ not be quoted" now, rather than "need not".

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an indexing problem?

No its a really bad coding problem.

Non-numeric values should be enclosed in quotes - actually literal values should always be enclosed in quotes when the underlying column type is numeric - otherwise you're likely to run into performance issues. You've also got a problem with managing errors in your code - if a query containing "WHERE style=5000B" is sent to the database it will always return an error - that you have no visibility of this error means that you've got a lot of important functionality missing from your site. Indeed, since content representations whould always be validated / changed at the point where the value leaves PHP, that also implies that your code is probably wide open to SQL injection attacks.

...and then there's the database design issues evident here: 'style' implies a non-unique identifier yet you are returning a single row from your query without any explicit ordering other than on the field you've selected on (i.e. even if it were unique, its very innefficient).

Answer (score 0):

try using single quotes here:

```
WHERE style='$color'
```